# Create table with values from one column and another column without intersection

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I have a table like so:

```
userid | clothesid
-------|-----------
  1    |   1
  1    |   3
  2    |   1
  2    |   4
  2    |   5
```

What I want from this table is a table like so:

```
userid | clothesid
-------|-----------
  1    |   4
  1    |   5
  2    |   3
```

How can I do this?

I've tried it with one entry as:

```
select distinct r.clothesid from table r where r.clothes not in (select r1.clothes from table r1 where r1.userid=1);
```

and this returns 4,5, but I'm not sure where to proceed from here

Answer (score 0):

You can `cross join` the list of  `userid`s and the list of `clothesid` to generate all combinations, and then use `not exists` on the original table to identify the missing rows:

```
select u.userid, c.clothesid
from (select distinct userid from mytable) u
cross join (select distinct clothesid from mytable) c
where not exists(
    select 1 from mytable t on t.userid = u.userid and t.clothesid = c.clothesid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select (case when t1.clothesid is not null then 2 else 1 end),
       coalesce(t1.clothesid, t2.clothesid)
from (select t.*
      from t
      where t.userid = 1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t.*
      from t
      where t.userid = 2
     ) t2
     on t1.clothesid = t2.clothesid
where t1.clothesid is null or t2.clothesid is null;
```

Actually, I think I have a simpler solution:

```
select (case when min(t.userid) = 1 then 2 else 1 end), clothesid
from t
group by clothesid
having count(*) = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fbedfa787e4df46c423d8a0074fd7bf3) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Left join all the combinations of `userid` and `clothesid` to the table and return only the unmatched rows:

```
select t1.userid, t2.clothesid
from (select distinct userid from tablename) t1
cross join (select distinct clothesid from tablename) t2
left join tablename t on t.userid = t1.userid and t.clothesid = t2.clothesid
where t.userid is null
```

Or with the operator [`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html):

```
select t1.userid, t2.clothesid
from (select distinct userid from tablename) t1
cross join (select distinct clothesid from tablename) t2
except
select userid, clothesid
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4ed888046a94998273cb70d409d9009f).
Results:

```
> userid | clothesid
> -----: | --------:
>      1 |         4
>      1 |         5
>      2 |         3
```